# How to overwrite method from interface?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, interface

I have an interface:

```
interface ISqlite
{
     DataTable select(SQLiteDatabase db);
}
```

And realization it:

```
public DataTable select(ISqlite s) {

    return s.select(driver);

}
```

As you can see method `select` is described with `DataTable` type in return.

How do I overwite this method so that it doesn't return a `DataTable`, but rather an Array or any other type?

I mean the following:

```
public Array select(ISqlite s) {

    return s.select(driver);

}
```

Comment: You can't do that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: For a class to implement an interface it has to match the signature of the methods exactly.  So, you'd need to update both the interface and all implementing classes.

Comment: You mean I need to write additional interface and add it to class?

Comment: You could do that yes.  And if your class implements both interfaces it will have two methods with different signatures that match each interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces were created in order to prevent you from doing just that.

Instead, do this:

```
interface ISqliteDatatable
{
     DataTable selectDataTable(SQLiteDatabase db);
}
interface ISqliteArray
{
     Array selectArray(SQLiteDatabase db);
}
```

Then when you make a class, decide which interface to implement based on your needs.

This solution is probably still not completely proper, but we don't know your overall design, so any further corrections would be higher level.

Here's how you would implement both:

```
public class example : ISqliteArray : ISqliteDataTable
{

    public DataTable selectDataTable(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        // Do stuff and return a datatable
    }


    public Array selectArray(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        // Do stuff and return an array
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, how then to call one of them method? Because I have one class that inherits both interfaces

Comment: If you have one class that implements both interfaces and you call `YourObject.select(db)`, what would you want it to return?

Comment: Edited to be more useful. Naming conventions aren't the best but it should get the point across. You could also combine those interfaces if ALL your classes needed BOTH methods.

Comment: Why `DataTable` in both cases?

Comment: Was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't change  the return type of a method (ie "override" as you wrote in your question)**
consider using [abstract class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d(v=vs.71).aspx) if you dont need to inherit another class, you will have the Ability to specify default implementations of methods.
you will need to write a separate method for each return type.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I wasn't sure, but still after trying a few more things, "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier, not a type".

Comment: I mean, I think the real answer is that the OP is trying to create a contract (interface) and then break the contract by changing the interface in implementation.  So it can't and shouldn't be done.  But was just trying it out of curiosity.  The other thing I tried was `public T select<T>(SQLiteDatabase db) where T : DataTable` but you get "constraints must match the constraints for parameter of interface method".

Comment: @ChrisBerger you are right, i will change or delete the answer, strange because visual studio did not show any error on design time when i tried that.

Comment: You could do something silly like implement `T select<T>()` and throw an exception if T isn't DataTable.   (And now that you've edited your answer, none of my comments make any sense at all... oh well...)

Comment: I would go for separate methods...its like trying to Insert a triangle into a square..